# How to create image from IplImage struct?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am not very familiar with old opencv codes. I have an `IplImage` struct:

```
IplImage *X;
```

This struct filled up with data that program reads from a device. I want to show it as image in my gui program. But I am not sure which properties I need to use.

EDIT:
Values of IplImage structs all properties with same order in docs(https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d5b/structIplImage.html):

```
4
0
0x557684eba3b4
0x557684eba3a4
GRAY
GRAYGRAY
0
16
192
0
�J�ಃ�O�ӳD������I���|�㲏�u������³��t�p�ݲ?�����F�Q�ⲿ���)���ҳ3�7�|�Ӳ������`�����_�I�_�Ͳ���{����E�5�p���(�(�D�|���L�L�W�����Q�,�r�D�L���ز��³�������������ҳ�̲�0������ܳ��,�³ǳj�׳��$�|�����u����N���$���Q�ȳ��ܳڳ��������
�J�ಃ�O�ӳD������I���|�㲏�u������³��t�p�ݲ?�����F�Q�ⲿ���)���ҳ3�7�|�Ӳ������`�����_�I�_�Ͳ���{����E�5�p���(�(�D�|���L�L�W�����Q�,�r�D�L���ز��³�������������ҳ�̲�0������ܳ��,�³ǳj�׳��$�|�����u����N���$���Q�ȳ��ܳڳ��������
0
49152
0
1
144
0
0
0
127
256
```

Comment: [The OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d5b/structIplImage.html) about `IplImage` exposes all the public members. I never used it but I think `IplImage::imageData` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Its a char* so an array but I couldnt find any info how to use it, and I am not sure actually how to create image from its value

Comment: Maybe try to see how it was filled by the program if you have access to the code. Or you can look for some information about the Intel Image Processing Library (which is what Ipl stands for) to see if there is some format definition.

Comment: For example, if you have a BGR image with 8 bit per pixel, use cv::Mat opencvImg = cv::Mat(cv::Size(ipl.width, ipl.height), CV_8UC3, ipl.imageData); however, this only works if the ipl-image has no padding or subimaging. If it has, you will have to use a cv::Mat constructor where you can assign the widthStep (step?) value and set it from ipl.widthStep and not sure, maybe you then need imageDataOrigin

Comment: @Micka Yes thank you, I can create an image with this Mat. I didnt learn if its expected image yet. They said all pixel has 0 to 65535 value once, so i used CV_16UC3 and it creates more normal image.

Comment: Can you print all the firlds of the iplImage struct?

Comment: @Micka I added to my post with same order in documentation. I am using 16UC1 by the way

Comment: Channels is 1 and depth is 16, so 16UC1 is the right type!

Comment: @Micka thanks for reply. But the output is not like what i expect. The output is empty black image but i am expecting something different. Maybe I need to do some operations on image?

Comment: can you find min and max values of the 16 bit image? When you render a 16 bit uint with cv::imshow it will expect darkest value to be 0 and brightest value to be 65535, so if for example all the actual pixel values are in the range of 0 to 255, they will be rendered very dark (very close to black). Can you cv::imwrite the cv::Mat as a `.png` and upload it?