# Proper Way to Save IplImage on Linux? (C++, opencv2)

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I'm attempting to save an image from a pointer variable of type `IplImage*`. I'm using C++ with `opencv` on a Raspberry Pi OS 32-bit. I installed the `opencv` library via the `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev` command from the terminal.

Firstly, it is my understanding that the image saving function changes from `opencv2` onwards, with the `cvSaveImage` function being replaced by the `imwrite` function on `opencv3` and onwards.

I'm using `opencv2`, therefore I should be able to call the `cvSaveImage` function with the arguments of my desired image filepath and the `IplImage*` pointer, however whenever I try to build my program with the `cvSaveImage` function, it prompts me with an error stating the function is not declared within the scope... All the other `opencv` functions I was calling were found successfully.

I'm not experienced with `opencv` at all, therefore I looked into the actual files I was including from the library.

I was including the `opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h` header files to access all my functions. After searching that header file, I was unable to find the `cvSaveImage` function anywhere.

Which file actually contains the `cvSaveImage` function that I'm looking for? Is it in a different file?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Get the type and pointer of pixel memory of your iplImage and map it to a cv::Mat header, then use cv::imwrite.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75297133/how-to-create-image-from-iplimage-struct?noredirect=1#comment132969469_75297133

Comment: But I don't think I can use the `imwrite` function... I'm using `opencv2`, not `opencv3`...

Comment: yeah, take the memory and wrap into a cv::Mat. -- please consult official documentation. not just _after_ v2 but **with** the v2 release everything changed. that was a long long time ago. you will simply not find anyone who's willing to support opencv v1 and the code is nearly impossible to find. some old v1 APIs existed in the v2 releases, purely to ease transition. v2 is long dead as well. we are currently at release **v4.7.0**

Comment: opencv 2.x did have cv::imwrite. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/16069407/2393191

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, it makes more sense. I'm able to create a `cv::Mat` object, however I'm running into an issue when attempting to call `cv::imwrite` anywhere in my code. It's telling me that it's an `undefined reference`, even though I `#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>` according to the documentation. If I look into that file, there indeed is no definition for that function, only a declaration. Where would I need to look to find the definition of the `cv::imwrite` function?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out that I had to include the object files for the functions declared in `imgcodecs.hpp`, by adding `-lopencv_imgcodecs` to my compile flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comments by Micka and Chrostoph Rackwitz, I found a workaround;

If one has iamge data in the form of a pointer variable `IplImage* imagePtr`, it can be saved to a file via the `cv::imwrite` command, in my case I used something along the lines of:

```
cv::imwrite("test.jpg", cv::Mat(height, width, type, imagePtr->imageData));
```